# Need to use a variable which used in for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, imageview, jsoup

I have an AsyncTask class and I have to use the variable to show pictures in an ImageView. I use jsoup library to parse html page and the problem is that I can't take my variable "bitmap" from doInBackground to onPostExecute method. How can I resolve my problem?
 Here is the code :

```
private class ParseHTML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        String resultTextFmt;
        Bitmap bm;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("WebMD");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            try{
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(mURL).get();

                Elements description2 = document.select("h2[class=et_pt_title]");
                Log.v("Data3", description2.toString());
                resultTextFmt = description2.toString();
                Elements divs = document.select("img");
                Log.w("DIVS_PICS", divs.toString());
                Bitmap  bitmap;
                for (Element div : divs) {
                    Log.d("web Stuff",div.text());


                  //  Element myImage = div;
                    String iurl;
                    iurl = div.absUrl("src");
                    Log.w("ABSurl:",iurl.toString());
                    URL url = new URL(iurl);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream()); // I need to get this var

                }
                bm = bitmap;

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bm); // and put it here to show 
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(resultTextFmt));
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your AsyncTask like this:

```
private class ParseHTML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params){
        Bitmap returnValue = new Bitmap();
        return returnValue;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
        imgView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
```

As you can see, you can parametrize result value as a Bitmap for `doInBackground()` at the Class definition. This way, you will also receive this value in `onPostExecute()` callback and handle the Bitmap there after composing it.

If you want to make it more sophisticated by also handling input args, or, for example, learn how to monitor the process, you have official documentation about AsyncTask [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: it works great! it seems that it is one possibly method to do it.